# how to build android kernel goldfish 2.6.29 and run it on qemu?

Tags: android, c, linux, gcc, android-kernel

I download source of android kernel with these commands:
`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish.git
git checkout -t origin/android-goldfish-2.6.29 -b goldfish`

then, I make some conf with these commands in goldfish directory 
`export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-
export ARCH=arm
export SUBARCH=arm
make goldfish_defconfig    # configure the kernel
make -j2                   # build it`

but after that i got these text on terminal:

`make: arm-eabi-gcc: Command not found
scripts/kconfig/conf -s arch/arm/Kconfig
make: arm-eabi-gcc: Command not found
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-arm
...
make[1]:  [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
Makefile:974: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
make:  [prepare0] Error 2`

and i tried to install arm-eabi-gcc with these commands:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-gcc-arm-embedded/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-embedded`
but nothing changes and got the `make: arm-eabi-gcc: Command not found` error again.

so do someone know how to fix this problem?
(i do this things on my ubuntu 17.04)

now that i use `arm-none-eabi-gcc` i got this error after i used `make -j2` command:
`scripts/kconfig/conf -s arch/arm/Kconfig
...
include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:86:30: fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc6.h: No such file or directory
 #include gcc_header(__GNUC__)
...
  HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost`

then i downgrade my gcc version to `gcc version 4.7.4 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.4-3ubuntu12)`
 but still get error `include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:86:30: fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc6.h: No such file or directory
 #include gcc_header(__GNUC__)` ! can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler binary in the `gcc-arm-ebedded` package is called `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, so you should set `CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-`.

Comment: do you know how to install arm-eabi-gcc on ubunutu 17.04?

Comment: Have you tried using `arm-none-eabi-gcc` instead? Why can't you use that compiler? Which ARM ABI variant do you need?

Comment: Actually i don't know their deffrence. I just follow this link:
[link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/refs/heads/master/docs/ANDROID-KERNEL.TXT)
i update the question as you said. please see the question again.